# Can you call a Python Function using a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, python, html, cgi

I've looked through the other questions in this website but none of them have the answers I'm looking for since most have code for jQuery, JSON, AJAX (if I can actually use it in the JavaScript function below, I'll use it), or try to download some files/programs/frameworks/packages to do it, like Flask, TkInter, or Django, none of I can use.

I need to do this without needing extra files.

So what I'm trying to do is get an HTML button called "Delete" to delete an image on another page called gallery.cgi on click and "Cancel" just redirects to gallery.cgi on click. main() does that but I can't call it in the HTML/JavaScript code. I need main() to only be called when "Delete" is clicked.

This is the function I'm trying to run in JavaScript, main() which uses a database file (for persistent storage) called test_shelf (stores images directory) and filename.db (stores filenames). Using this, it deletes the last image stored in the db files.

```
import cgi, os
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
import shelve

images = shelve.open('test_shelf.db', writeback = True)
imageTitle = "Armory" # Title of image being deleted
def main():
    db = shelve.open('filename.db', writeback = True)
    try:
      if db['key']:
        alist = db['key']           # read
        _filename = alist[-1]           # last element of list
        images.pop(_filename, None)
        alist.remove(_filename)
        db['key'] = alist           # writeback
        if os.path.exists('pictures/' + _filename): # pictures is where I store the images, so I need to delete them.
          os.remove('pictures/' + _filename)
    finally:
      db.close()
```

This is the JavaScript function that I want to call the python function in.

```
function deletePicture() {
  // Call main() here, so only clicking "Delete" button can delete an image
  location.href='gallery.cgi';
}
```

And this is the code in HTML that calls deletePicture() OnClick. The button called Delete calls deletePicture() on click, which should call main() and it will delete the last image stored in db and then redirect to gallery.cgi.

```
<p>Are you sure? You want to delete picture [ <b>"""
print imageTitle
print """</b> ].</p>
  <input type = "button" value = "Delete" onClick = "return deletePicture()"/>
  <input type = "button" value = "Cancel" onClick = "location.href='gallery.cgi';"/>
```

Note that all of this is in the same file (delete.cgi), which is a Python CGI. All the HTML/JavaScript code is printed by python code.
(I can't make another file (.py) that has the main() code and then call it in delete.cgi, I'm only allowed to use one .cgi file to perform delete.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can call main by having your delete input connect to gallery.cgi/main/ and then executing os.environs['PATH'] as a method in the CGI file.

HTML:

```
<input type = "button" value = "Delete" onClick = "location.href='gallery.cgi/main/'"/>
```

Python (something like):

```
if os.environs['PATH']:
    path = os.environs['PATH']
    locals()[path]()
```

You could also replace either of those inputs with a link and href, if this is the only function they perform. And you would also want to check whether os.environs['PATH'] is an available method to run.